# Self-modifying Python code to keep track of high scores

Tags: python, self-modifying

I've considered storing the high scores for my game as variables in the code itself rather than as a text file as I've done so far because it means less additional files are required to run it and that attributing 999999 points becomes harder.

However, this would then require me to run self-modifying code to overwrite the global variables representing the scores *permanently*. I looked into that and considering that all I want to do is really just to change global variables, all the stuff I found was too advanced.

I'd appreciate if someone could give me an explanation on how to write self-modifying Python code to do *just* that, preferably with an example too as it aids understanding.

Comment: Have you considered simply saving the file as binary so it cannot be read?

Comment: Don't do this. Just encrypt them. Total security is pretty much impossible (it's the same problem as DRM), but possibly encrypted binary should be enough to stop any casual user.

Comment: I don't think "less additional files" should be a consideration when writing a program. Some of my favorite games have dozens and dozens of config files and save files and sound effect files and subdirectories and... It doesn't make them any less fun to play.

Comment: if it's good enough for roller coaster tycoon, it's good enough for you

Comment: @marsh If by binary you mean an executable file, it's what I have been doing in the first place actually. The problem right now though is that the executable can't permanently update the scores, possibly because its resources have to be extracted to a temporary folder first (making them accessible too) and aren't retrieved, but I have no idea how to do that either, so right now I'm here. (If that wasn't what you meant I'll have to apologize and ask for further details, as unfortunately my computing terminology isn't very advanced...)

Comment: @sweeneyrod I'm honestly just looking for some way to avoid there being an embarrassingly obvious way for a player to give himself any score. I hope it didn't sound like I wanted any of the latest high-tech security/encryption options... it's just a game.

Comment: @Kevin "less additional files" was indeed not a consideration when I was developing the game, but it became one as soon as distributing it and "which one do I open?" were brought up.

Comment: That's one of the drawbacks of Python, yeah... Users are likely to look for a "[gamename].exe" file to double click on, but Python doesn't produce executables. You could always put startup instructions in the README, I suppose.

Comment: You could build an executable using py2exe (or equivalent programs), which are fairly easy to use. You can then bundle the files produced into an installer.

Comment: @sweeneyrod The thing is I already tried py2exe, PyInstaller and cx_freeze. py2exe never works because of some "Segmentation Fault" that I unsuccessfully tried to fix for 6 months, cx_freeze produces way too many files and PyInstaller does literally everything I need except for keeping the highscores saved after exiting the game. Honestly I _would_ prefer fixing whatever PyInstaller's issue is but at the same time I'm trying as many different ways as possible here to increase my chance of at least one of them working perfectly.

Comment: Consider LISP or Prolog for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first inclination is to say "don't do that".  Self-modifying Python (really any language) makes it extremely difficult to maintain a versioned library.

1. You make a bug fix and need to redistribute - how do you merge data you stored via self-modification.
2. Very hard to authenticate packaging using a hash - once the local version is modified it's hard to tell which version it originated because SHAs won't match.
3. It's unsafe - You could just save and load a Python class that's not stored with your package, however, if it's user writable, a foreign process could add any arbitrary Python code to that file to evaluate.  Kind of like SQL injection but Python style.

Python makes is so trivial to load and dump JSON files, that for simple things, I wouldn't think of anything else.  Even CSV files are trivial and can be bound to maps but can be more easily manipulated as data using your favorite spreadsheet editor.

My suggestion - don't use self-modifiying Python unless you're just wanting to experiment; It's just not a practical solution in the real world, unless you're working in an embedded environment where disk and memory are a premium.

Comment: I honestly haven't thought about any issues related to self-modification other than the coding itself (and getting it to work). I would actually be willing to experiment right now, but now it sounds like it wouldn't actually bring me much closer to what I am actually looking to achieve... thanks for the heads up, I guess.